# Sensu Client status

Tags: sensu

I am trying to see why my Sensu Client does not connect to my Sensu Server.
How can I see the status of the client and whether it tried, succeeded, failed in connecting with the server?

1. I have installed Sensu Server on CentOS using docker. I can connect to it, the RabbiMQ and Uchiwa panel from my host.
2. I have installed Sensu Client on Windows host.
3. I have added following configs:

> C:\etc\sensu\conf.d\client.json

```
{
  "client": {
    "name": "DanWindows",
    "address": " 192.168.59.3",
    "subscriptions": [ "all" ]
  }
}
```

> C:\etc\sensu\config.json

```
{
  "rabbitmq": {
    "host": "192.168.59.103",
    "port": 5671,
    "vhost": "/sensu",
    "user": "sensu",
    "password": "password",
    "ssl": {
      "cert_chain_file": "C:/etc/sensu/ssl/cert.pem",
      "private_key_file": "C:/etc/sensu/ssl/key.pem"
    }
  }
}
```

4. I have installed and started the Sensu Client service using following command:

   `sc create sensu-client binPath= C:\Tools\sensu\bin\sensu-client.exe DisplayName= "Sensu Client"`
5. On the Uchiwa panel I do not see any clients.
6. The "sensu-client.err.log" and "sensu-client.out.log" are empty, while "sensu-client.wrapper.log" contains this:

   `2015-01-16 13:41:51 - Starting C:\Tools\sensu\embedded\bin\ruby C:\Tools\sensu\embedded\bin\sensu-client -d C:\etc\sensu\conf.d -l C:\Tools\sensu\sensu-client.log
   2015-01-16 13:41:51 - Started 3800`

How can I see the status of the Windows client and whether it tried, succeeded, failed in connecting with the server?

Comment: Which version of sensu you are using ? I think the latest version I am using has the configuration files in `/etc/sensu/conf.d/` and not in `/etc/sensu/`  In `conf.d` I am having two config files client.json and rabbitmq.json and no config.json in `/etc/sensu`. I am running sensu 0.16

Answer (score 0):

Question on the docker, is this one you built yourself?  I recently built my own as well only using Ubuntu instead of CentOS.

Recent versions of sensu require the following two files in the `/etc/sensu/conf.d` directory:

`/etc/sensu/conf.d/rabbitmq.json`

`/etc/sensu/conf.d/client.json`

The client.json file will have contents similar to this:

```
{   "client": {
       "name": "my-sensu-client",
       "address": "192.168.x.x",
       "subscriptions": [ "ALL" ] }
}
```

The only place I have heard of needing a `config.json` file is on the sensu-server.  But I have only recently been looking at sensu so this may be an older sensu requirement.